# JSF - Focus component that failed validation

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF 2.0 application using Primefaces 3.0M4 component library. I have the following input:

```
<p:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.value}" required="true">
      <p:ajax event="blur" update="msg" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message id="msg" for="input" />
```

what I would like to do is that in case validation fails (the value is empty), focus returns to the component, forcing the user to enter a value. is this possible?
Also I would like that when user clicks the submit button; if validation fails there, the first component that did not pass the validation is focused.

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, client-side, by using the `required` and `requiredMessage` attributes. The user can't submit the form and a error message is shown:

```
<h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />  
        <p:inputText id="firstname"   
                value="#{personBean.firstname}"   
                required="true" requiredMessage="You have to enter your name" label="Firstname">  
            <f:validateLength minimum="2" />  
        </p:inputText>  
        <p:message for="firstname" />
```

You could use `primefaces message` if you don't use `requiredMessage` attribute, because it will show you two warning messages and it's a bit strange...

For the focus it depends...what if you have two inputTexts? Do you want to show the focus only for the first one? 
You can see a demo here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprAjaxStatusScript.jsf

Comment: thanks @spauny the first part was already working, my question was about the focus. catagay civici's answer is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Damian Yeah, I forgot about focus, actually I never used it... so no worry, after all he is the primefaces boss! :D